# Itō-Stratonovich correction term for SPDEs

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

Where can I find a derivation of the Itō-Stratonovich correction term for [Itō-SPDEs as considered by Da Prato](https://books.google.de/books?id=bxkmAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=%22We+proceed+to+study+nonlinear+equations%22&source=bl&ots=-3frQaVU7s&sig=DGCN5h-8fq9tqf_7_YqPO_6JUuQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF1sv5mL_PAhWDBsAKHVOwBRQQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22We%20proceed%20to%20study%20nonlinear%20equations%22&f=false)? I know how we obtain the [correction term for finite dimensional SDEs](https://books.google.de/books?id=r9r6CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22is+also+a+solution+of+the+Stratonovich+SDE%22+%22with+modified+drift%22&source=bl&ots=Zq0cfWKkiY&sig=OvlYvnBzfhjRWedDC3S7O44dTko&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMlfWvmr_PAhXpLMAKHSGjAFwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20also%20a%20solution%20of%20the%20Stratonovich%20SDE%22%20%22with%20modified%20drift%22&f=false), but I can't find any textbook$^1$ which is studying Stratonovich-SPDEs and the relation to their corresponding Itō-SPDEs.

---

$^1$ Actually, there *is* a textbook, but the [derivation of the correction term presented there](https://books.google.de/books?id=NvXJAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=%22the+Stratonovich+SPDE%22+%22converts+to+the+following%22&source=bl&ots=xsP7ocUAvF&sig=pEOXkIpZwZxZvJ0CVwVBJ-iat1Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV6JCIm7_PAhXHIsAKHQgeB78Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20Stratonovich%20SPDE%22%20%22converts%20to%20the%20following%22&f=false) isn't very rigorously.